# In Laravel 5.2, Laravel Cashier stripe can'not create subscription.

Tags: php, stripe-payments, laravel-5, laravel-cashier

I am using Laravel 5.2 and Cashier.
I want create subscription

```
 $user->newSubscription('premium', 'monthly')->create($request->get('stripeToken'));
```

And I get this error

Api in RequestOptions.php line 78:
The second argument to Stripe API method calls is an optional per-request apiKey, which must be a string, or per-request options, which must be an array. (HINT: you can set a global apiKey by "Stripe::setApiKey()")

Comment: I found the problem. In .env stripe key should be defined only with STRIPE_KEY name. I use my random name, this is a problem, after change it to STRIPE_KEY everything ok.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem today - the reason behind it is that the `Laravel\Cashier\Billable::getStripeKey()` method gets the environment variable by using `getenv('STRIPE_SECRET')` instead of actually using config, which forces you to have the environment variable called `STRIPE_SECRET` - I had mine named differently and that was causing the problem - so make sure that your environment variable for the stripe's secret key is named `STRIPE_SECRET`.

The method that's causing the problem:

```
/**
 * Get the Stripe API key.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public static function getStripeKey()
{
    return static::$stripeKey ?: getenv('STRIPE_SECRET');
}
```